# Chat send message left received right

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello I made a chat with Javascript and now i want the send message to be displayed at the left and the received at the right. 
HTML

```
<div id="chatHtml" style="display: none;">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/main.css">
        <div id=chatOutput class="chat-output"></div>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" id="input-text-chat" placeholder="Enter Text Chat"></textarea> 
        <div id="chat-container">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
 openChat: function(){
        win =window.open('','myconsole',
        'width=450,height=500'
        +',menubar=0'
        +',toolbar=1'
        +',status=0'
        +',scrollbars=1'
        +',resizable=1')
        win.document.writeln("<body style='background-color:#ecf0f1'></body>");
        chat = document.getElementById("chatHtml").innerHTML;
        win.document.write(chat);
        win.document.title = "Live Chat"; 

    win.document.getElementById('input-text-chat').onkeyup = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode != 13) return;
    // removing trailing/leading whitespace
    this.value = this.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');

     var a = new Date();
     var b = a.getHours(); var c = a.getMinutes(); var d = a.getSeconds();
     if(b < 10){b = '0'+b;} 
     if(c < 10){c = '0'+c;} 
     if(d < 10){d = '0'+d;}
     var time = b+':'+c+':'+d;

    if (!this.value.length) return
   win.document.getElementById("chat-container").className="chat-Output";
    connection.send('<div class="bubbleGET"> <font color="white"> User(' + time + '): ' +this.value+ '</font></div>');
    console.log(connection.send);
    console.log('User (' + time + '): ' +this.value);
  win.document.getElementById("chat-container").className="chat-OutputGET";
    appendDIV('<div class="bubble"> <font color="white"> User (' + time + '): ' +this.value+ '</font></div>');
    this.value = '';
    };
    var chatContainer = win.document.querySelector('.chat-output');
    function appendDIV(event) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = event.data || event;
    chatContainer.appendChild(div);
    div.tabIndex = 0;
    div.focus();
    win.document.getElementById('input-text-chat').focus();
        }
    connection.onmessage = appendDIV;

    }
}
```

win.document.getElementById("chat-container").className="chat-OutputGET"; doesnt work

Here's the css for the class:

```
.chat-Output{
  position: absolute; bottom: 2.1em;
  margin-left: 0.4em;
  padding-left: 0.4em;
  overflow: scroll;
  word-break: break-word;
}

.chat-OutputGET{
  position: absolute; bottom: 2.1em;
  margin-right: 0.4em;
  overflow: scroll;
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

Thanks :)
I have to say that i'm new to web development.

Comment: Could you please create a JSFiddle with the code sample?

Comment: I tried then there is not design at all.

Comment: @Reflamer jsfiddle doesn't like document.write

Answer (score 2):

just use `float:left`

and `clear:both` in your styling

Answer (score 0):

No need for absolute positioning. You can use `float` and `clear`. See my example here https://jsfiddle.net/yev1cwa0/